# Deleting chr160 characters in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

In the following code I would like to delete the `char 160` and `34` characters at the end of the text string.

```
For Column = 12 To 13

    For i = 16 To last_row
        'sString = ("=CODE(160)")
        'Range(Cells(i, Column), Cells(i, Column)).Select
        'Range(Cells(last_row + 1, Column), Cells(last_row + 1, Column)).Value = Replace(Range(Cells(i, Column), Cells(i, Column)).Value, sString, "", 1, -1)

        Set current_cell = Range(Cells(i, Column), Cells(i, Column))
        current_cell.Select

        text_to_change = Range(Cells(i, Column), Cells(i, Column)).Value

        Range(Cells(last_row + 1, Column), Cells(last_row + 1, Column)).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        With Range(Cells(last_row + 1, Column), Cells(last_row + 1, Column))
        .Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(" & text_to_change & ";CODE(160);" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
        .Value = .Value
        End With

    Next i

Next Column
```

I'm getting an error at this line:

`.Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(" & text_to_change & ";CODE(160);" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"`.

The error message indicates:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Could you help me what is wrong here?

Comment: Why not use : `.Replace Chr(160), "", xlPart`?

Comment: Why not just `.Value = Replace(Replace(.Value, chr(160), vbNullString), chr(34), vbNullString)`, and skip the `.Formula` altogether?  (Also, `chr(160)` is Non Breaking Space - did you also want `Char(32)`, which is a "normal" Space?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quote marks:

```
.Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(""" & text_to_change & """;CODE(160);""" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & """)"
```

Comment: +1: This is why Step 1 of "My `.Formula =` doesn't work" should always be to swap `.Formula =` for `Debug.Print`, and read the output *carefully*